# Why 360 degrees is in the top instead of 90 degrees in aviation?

Tags: navigation, aeronautical-charts

Normally on 2D map, if there is point say A(0,0) in the center and there is point B in the 2nd quadrant . The angle is always in 90<=x<=180. But in aviation, it is 270<=x<=360 . Why ?

Treat this as a basic question. 
[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Because of compass headings? I've never heard of a map liked you describe. Mathematical planes have angle systems that are 90 degrees rotated and counterclockwise from compass headings.

Comment: Normal maps have 0 or 360 degrees at the top, I've never seen a map with 90 degrees at the top.

Comment: Can you add an example of a "normal" map that has 90 degrees at the top? That might help to make your question clearer.

Comment: In the (really) old days, some maps had east at the top. "European cartographers oriented their maps towards the Holy Land since Jerusalem was the place of Christ’s death and resurrection.  In fact, the world “orient” comes from the Latin word “oriens”, meaning East." (snippet from https://www.geolounge.com/map-orientation/)

Comment: @J.Hougaard: The [etymology of orient](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oriens) is associated with "rising", like rising Sun. More or less the same India-European proto-origin than "aurora". Occident itself comes from "falling down".

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [Polar coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) do not typically have 0° oriented in the "North" direction. The difference is between Cartesian coordinate system, and an [Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed (ECEF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) or [Geodetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum) system, which is used for navigation and mapping purposes.

Comment: @RonBeyer OK, fair enough, a more precise point.

Answer (score 6):

Conventionally, geographical maps are shown with the North up and North is also by convention 0 degrees (or 360), which is equal to the compass heading of North. The angle increases clockwise, with 90 degrees being East. This is not specific to aviation; in fact during flight the preferred presentation is to have the map oriented such that the direction of flight is upward.

The mathematical plane you seem to describe on the left has the primary axis as the angular datum (also by convention, [more info here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1252160/74898) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1749279/74898)). So the positive x-axis is 0 degrees. The angle increases counterclockwise, so the positive y-axis is 90 degrees.

Answer (score 5):

Because that is how compass directions work. A magnetic compass points towards the [magnetic] North Pole, because of the way the Earth's magnetic field is oriented, which makes it very convenient to use north as a starting point when it comes to compass directions.

[image]

North is the starting point, and is equal to 0 (or 360) degrees. The number then increases clockwise.

This is in no way unique to aviation. Almost all types of navigation rely on this standard, including maritime and aviation.